# How can I trick my OS/browser into beliving that my mouse click is locked/clicked continuesly?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, automation

Ubuntu 20.04. I'm trying to play a single player browser game where I have to move the cursor around in order to quickly move the object. But it requires me to keep a hold on the mouse button in order to do so. There is no point of holding the left-click mouse button the entire time. So, I would like to to believe that I'm holding the mouse button while I'm not, so that all I'll have to do is to move the mouse cursor only without having to mechanically hold the left-click myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On xorg, but not on Wayland (default on Ubuntu versions from 21.10 onwards), you can use `xdotool` with the `mousedown` command to simulate you pressing the mouse button.

```
xdotool mousedown 1
```

See `man xdotool` for the documentation on the tool.

Also a system that defaults to Wayland can be switched to run on xorg again: on the login screen, click the cog and select "Ubuntu on Xorg" before entering your password.

Wayland users may try `ydotool`, which is in rather early development. Also there, with

```
ydotool click --down --buttons left
```

you can simulate pressing down the mousebutton without releasing it.

To trick your browser, assign such a command to a shortcut key ("Settings" - "Keyboard") so you can trigger it while using the browser.

Comment: Please consider a noob here. I didn't understand much of what you said. I did try "xdotool mousedown" command but it looks like it's incomplete and I need to add more info to it. Check the output [here](https://pastebin.com/E9k9eLvp). Eventually if it works, then I would try to add it to the keyboard shortcuts in the end like you mentioned.

Comment: The mouse button must be specified: I updated the answer.